# Glassfish doesnot start as a service at bootup at Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, glassfish

As far as I know command statement below is used to create Glassfish service,
After execution following command. GlassFish_domain1 file is created under /etc/init.d directory. And link files are created at each directory /etc/rc0.d, /etc/rc1.d ... /etc/rc6.d

```
asadmin create-service
```

But when I have restarted the machine on which Glassfish is installed, Glassfish does not start.

Here is the file created **GlassFish_domain1**

```
ASADMIN="/root/Downloads/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin"

case "$1" in
start)
    $ASADMIN start-domain    --domaindir /root/Downloads/glassfish3/glassfish/domains  domain1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    ;;
stop)
    $ASADMIN stop-domain   --domaindir /root/Downloads/glassfish3/glassfish/domains  domain1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    ;;
restart)
    $ASADMIN restart-domain   --domaindir /root/Downloads/glassfish3/glassfish/domains  domain1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    ;;
*)
    echo "usage: $0 (start|stop|restart|help)"
esac
```

**Links.**

```
   /etc/rc0.d/K20glassfish -> ../init.d/GlassFish_domain1
   /etc/rc1.d/K20glassfish -> ../init.d/GlassFish_domain1
   /etc/rc6.d/K20glassfish -> ../init.d/GlassFish_domain1
   /etc/rc2.d/S20glassfish -> ../init.d/GlassFish_domain1
   /etc/rc3.d/S20glassfish -> ../init.d/GlassFish_domain1
   /etc/rc4.d/S20glassfish -> ../init.d/GlassFish_domain1
   /etc/rc5.d/S20glassfish -> ../init.d/GlassFish_domain1
```

I have checked it out agin that I am having 127 exit status when glassfish gets run automatically.??

Comment: What can you find within the log file in /root/Downloads/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/log/server.log ?

Comment: There is nothing. I think something does not allow execution.

Comment: if you start /etc/init.d/GlassFish_domain1 all works fine?

Comment: yes if I execute "/etc/init.d/GlassFish_domain1 start" manually all work fine.

Comment: UPDATED question. I am having 127 exist status somehow.

Comment: 127 is refered as "command not found".
change the ASADMIN line like this (think this is wrong) - 
ASADMIN=/root/Downloads/glassfish3/bin/asadmin

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7029/discussion-between-patricks-and-mmc18)

Comment: I have found out the problem. JAVA_HOME has to be set and JAVA_HOME/bin has to inserted in to PATH. Actually I did same setting in "/root/.profile" but perhaps before  execution of .profile script  runlevel scripts run.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the problem. JAVA_HOME has to be set and JAVA_HOME/bin has to be inserted in to PATH in script under /etc/rcX.d X is the runlevel index number. Actually I did same setting in "/root/.profile" but perhaps before execution of ".profile"  scripts under /etc/rcX.d run.